# Remove a string from the url with Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my url:

http://example.com/index.php*#motto*

On page load remove **#motto** with Javascript.

Comment: you need to alter the window.location property in this case.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: `window.location.hash=""`

Comment: Whit that the url became this: http://example.com/index.php#. Can i remove the #?

Comment: i would suggest you to check history.pushState function

Comment: will be something like this: `history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);` but it is not cross browser, in ie8 or ie9 i don't think it will work

Answer (score -1):

```
$.fn.urlHash = function()
{
  return window.location.hash.replace('#','');
};
$.urlHash();
```

Comment: Please a some comments about the code you are providing.

Comment: Why assign a stateless function to the jQuery (or similar)  global object?

Comment: The post was edited. He was asking about jquery.I was just trying to answer like him asked. Ok teacher!